# C++ and OpenMP: How to make the initializer list of a constructor critical?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, openmp

In C++ with OpenMP, is it possible to make the operations performed in the initializer list of a constructor critical in the sense of `#pragma omp critical`?

Answer (score -1):

As the syntax for a `critical` construct in OpenMP is:

```
#pragma omp critical [(name)] new-line
structured-block
```

the only way I see to have the operations performed in an initializer list of a constructor critical is to *define them critical* inside the class being initialized. To better explain myself:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base() {
#pragma omp critical
    {
      /* Some critical operation here */
    }
  }

  /* ... */
}

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() : Base() {} // Here base call some critical code

  /* ... */
}
```

If there is a need to make the operations in `Base` constructor critical only in a few objects, I would personally try to devise two different `Base` policies and restructure `Derived` to be an host class (see chapter 1 of ["Modern C++ Design"](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/) for a reference on policies).
The reasoning remains obviously the same if aggregation, rather than inheritance, is taken into consideration.